# Change input value with Javascript, correct syntax

Tags: javascript

I want to change input value after ajax success, I do next:

At the top of function I use:

```
var input = document.getElementById("input_id").value;
```

Later on ajax success I tried next but doesn't work:

```
input = 'test value';
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: can you post you code part

Comment: To extend on why specifically your version doesn't work: numbers and strings are passed by value in javascript. Your `input` variable will not have any reference to the original input value, just the value coming from it

Comment: "doesnt work"? nothign happens? or error happens? what does error say?

Answer (score 3):

After you assign `var input = document.getElementById("input_id").value;`, `input` becomes a string and is no longer a live reference to the input field.

You can do something like `document.getElementById("input_id").value = 'test value'`.

Alternatively, you can keep a reference to it by just `var input_element = document.getElementById("input_id")`, and then getting or setting it via `input_element.value`.

Answer (score 3):

The variable `input` you're using is the EXACT value of the input field at the time of declaration. It is not a reference to input field's `value` property.

You should just use a reference to the `input` element and then set its value like so-

```
var input = document.getElementById("input_id");

// Do some ajax call

input.value = 'test value'
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `document.getElementById("input_id");` to get the reference of the input element which can be then used to set the value or manipulate the input element. Use `input.value = 'test value';` to assign value to this input element. So, this was wrong in your code as you were assigning the value to the value of input element itself.

```js
//get the reference of the input element
var input = document.getElementById("input_id");
//assign value to this input element
input.value = 'test value';
```

```html
<input id='input_id' type='text' />
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to change the value of `input field` then, this should work

```
document.getElementById("input_id").value = "test-value";
```